# Removing charAt from c string

Tags: c, string, char

I am trying to write simple removeAt(char* str, int pos) in C, but confused by result.

```
char c[] = "abcdef";
char* c1 = removeAt(c, 3);

cout << c1;
```

If I am doing it in this way:

```
static char* removeAt(char* str, int pos)
{
   int i = 0;

   for(i = pos; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
       str[i] = str[++i];
   }

   str[i] = '\0';

   return str;
}
```

string stays the same **"abcdef";**

If I am doing:

```
static char* removeAt(char* str, int pos)
{
 int i, k =0;

for(i = pos, k = pos;  str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
   str[i] = str[++k];
}

str[i] = '\0';

return str;
}
```

does work as intended.

Comment: In your first example, you increment `i` twice per loop. In the second, you only increment `i` and `k` one time each.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `strcpy ( str + pos, str + pos + 1 );`?

Comment: was just playing with string manipulation for interview preparation, haven't touched it in forever.

Comment: @unxnut strcpy doesn't allow overlapping strings. It may work for if you try it, but it change without notice (there was a bug in the Linux kernel caused by the same reason in `memcpy`)

Comment: I had tried it on Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) with gcc (3.4.5) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop

```
for(i = pos; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    str[i] = str[++i];
}
```

You change the value of `i` by doing `i++`, so you end up missing a character every two, or something similar. Change `i++` to `i+1`.

EDIT: By the way, the line

```
str[i] = str[++i]
```

is undefined behaviour, since it's not specified when the increment will occur (before or after evaluating the left side?). If the right side is evaluated first then your code would be

```
i++;
str[i] = str[i];
```

Effectively doing nothing, as you observe.

Comment: If you feel like the answer solved your question, you should probably click the check button to accept it.

Comment: Thank you Andrey, but as hard as my feelings are to accept this answer, I am unable to do it yet, because of the SO rules.